# Date Range doesn’t work with joins condition Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a query that joins admin users with posts that they created for a specified month. The results I am getting, are finding the current month & including the records for the month after it. How can I only find records for the specified month with my joins statement?

**admins_controller.rb**

index.html

```
@admin_users = User.where(admin: true).joins(:posts).where(posts: {created_at: Date.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, 1).beginning_of_month..Date.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, 1).end_of_month}).distinct
```

Comment: What is the exact result you are expecting? Your current result should hold all admin users that made at least one post in the provided timeframe. Worth noting is that if you then call `@admin_users.first.posts` it will return all posts of the user, not only the posts in the provided timeframe. Are you expecting `@admin_users.first.posts` to return only the posts of the user in the provided timeframe?

Comment: It’s not even working with joins & merge(Post). Weird. I’m using Postgres as my DB

Comment: Let me restate - The query shown above in the question body is returning the records for the month specified & the month after it. Even though I am using the date range & distinct, correctly.

Comment: How can you get the records after `current month`. those should not be present in the db

Comment: I don’t know. It’s being joined somehow

Comment: Let me ask it simpler. What exactly do you expect to be in the current month?

Comment: My expectation is that only 07/01/2020-07/31/2020 when the query fires off. It seems that the query is ignoring the date constraints & adding all dates.

Comment: I parsed the date before saving it. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Your expectations are completely off. This will create an inner join and thus load records from users that have at least one row in the joined table. It will not limit the records loaded from posts which may be loaded in a separate query since you are using `.includes`.

Comment: Is there a way to get User and their Posts for a specific month? Or date range?

Comment: I used a very hacky approach that includes iterating over the records in view